# Error loading .atn files through Javascript

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

Hello I'm new to scripting in Photoshop.

I'm trying to load a atn file into photoshop through script.  I'm sure I had it working when I was initially scouting out this script, but now whenever I try to run it I get an error

> Error 1233: Expected a reference to an existing File/Folder line 2 -> app.load(new File(path));

Below is my stripped down code.  I cut down the path as small as I could in case I had a typo, but still no luck.

```
var path = "C:\\test.atn";
app.load(new File(path));
```

Loading the .atn file through File->Open menu works so I don't think it's a problem with the .atn file.

Comment: Note that questions about PS scripting are almost certainly going to get more/better answers over on https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem/ct-p/ct-photoshop - especially as loading from `C:\` means you're locking your script into Windows, even though PS is platform agnostic, and its scripting should be too. The folks over on the PS community forums will be able to help you much better for this specific type of programming question.

Comment: good point I'll throw it up there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially had problems with this. The script is fine.

```
function load_action (apath)
{
    var actionFile = new File(apath);
    if(!actionFile.exists)
    {
        alert("Action file does not exist! \n" + apath);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        app.load(actionFile);
        alert("loaded!");
    }
}
```

However... I was accessing the script above through an action - which I've got on a shortcut and there was a action load/play conflict.

**Could not complete your request because an action that is playing or recording can't be deleted.**

Try the above and use File...Scripts...(Browse) to access you script.

Comment: Nope still getting the error.  This looks a lot like my un-stripped down version.  When I was testing with it, actionFile.exists does come back true, but then app.load() triggers the error.

Comment: oh it's working again.  Not sure why it had stopped.